# FileWriter don't write string with 78510 length

Tags: java, android, gson, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a problem, i have a list of MyObject, and i want to write this in a file in  json.

So i parse my list with gson to json and i write the string in file, but nothing have been write the file was create but is empty (0 octet).

if my `List<MyObject>` have 60 item and i parse it to json, the string have a  14482 lenght, and the Filewriter work fine.

if my `List<MyObject>` have 60+ item and i parse it to json the Filewriter do nothing, and the file is empty.
For exemple if my list have 300 item the length is 78909

Here is my code for write my list in file:

```
 private void saveTrace() {
    try {
        Log.d(mapsActivity.TAGDEBUG, "Sauvegarde de la trace automatique");
        Log.d(mapsActivity.TAGDEBUG, "Nombre de point compris dans la trace automatique: " + String.valueOf(listBeanTraceUser.size()));
        String sFileNameTrace = "trace_" + currentDate + ".xml";
        File traceFile = new File(root, sFileNameTrace);

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mapsActivity, new String[]{traceFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(traceFile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer, 32768);
        String jsonStringTrace = gson.toJson(listBeanTraceUser);
        Log.d(mapsActivity.TAGDEBUG, "lenght jsonStringTrace : " + String.valueOf(jsonStringTrace.length()));
        out.write(jsonStringTrace);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(mapsActivity.TAGDEBUG, "Erreur lors de la Sauvegarde de la trace automatique");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
out.flush();
```

between writing and closing the file to make sure it was completely done.

It's because you use a BufferedWriter with an internal buffer with a size of 32768

Comment: if i remove the size it's the same. I will try to save one by one not all the list

Comment: @Slasch Did you add the required out.flush() method call before closing the writer ?

Comment: @Slasch BTW, you don't close the writer too. Try to add a writer.close() call too.

Comment: Finally i save one object ''trace' by one. When i get a "trace" i save directly in a file, and i append other after. This is more secure, if my app close for x reason i have something in my file. Thank Cedric L

Answer (score 0):

try use PrintWriter/PrintStream to write in file。like this:

```
PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(writer); 
printWriter.println(jsonStringTrace );
printWriter.close();
```